# Are elements of a group are also elements of the quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think the general answer to this question is no. What I struggle about the notation of a question in Thomas Hungerford's Abstract Algebra An Introduction Textbook. The question is the following;

Find the order of $\frac{8}{9}$ in the additive group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. But

$$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \{\mathbb{Z}+g:g\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$
So we have that $\frac{8}{9}\notin \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

but $\mathbb{Z}+\frac{8}{9}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Moreover, how can a quotient group be additive? I know the result is same and is $9$ but I am a little bit confused about the notation and I could not figure out the possible mistake I am conducting.

Comment: It's common to use the same notation for the group element and its image in the quotient, especially when context makes it clear which is intended.

Comment: You are right, probably the author wrote $8/9$ as a representative for the class $\mathbb{Z}8/9$.

Comment: This is known in the trade as abuse of notation, and we all do it all the time, so you have to learn to live with it!

Comment: In more advanced books of algebra it would make more sense but in an introductory book it makes harder to understand what is going on. Since I am learning these stuff anew, I just get into suspicion if I did not learn these properly. Thanks for the all comments, best regards!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}g$ is misleading. This a quotient of additive groups and so the cosets should be $g+\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the quotient group is a different group with different elements. The author just decided to use a more simple notation than $\mathbb{Z}\frac{8}{9}$, it happens a lot in mathematics. By the term "additive" he means that here the operation in $\mathbb{Q}$ is addition. Hence the operation of the quotient group is $\mathbb{Z}a\mathbb{Z}b=\mathbb{Z}(a+b)$. Actually, in this type of groups I prefer to write the elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as $a+\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $a\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think it's unfair to call the author "lazy" here! We don't know their motivation. It is just as likely that they abused the notation like this as having a million $\mathbb{Z}$s kicking around would make everything harder to read.

Comment: Maybe I should have written it in other words, though as you can see OP actually had problems understanding this exercise because of this non standard notation.

Comment: Well, you can edit your answer to use other words :-) [I don't think the notation is ideal, but I also don't think it is fair to speculate on the reasons for the author using it. Writing a book is a massive task, and one not undertaken by someone who is "lazy"!]